# Cannot open the AWS s3 bucket Object URL using google chrome how to fix this issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded a pdf version file into the AWS s3 bucket bucket and then tried to open that object url using Google Chrome. The following error occurred. How to fix this issue?

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>5FEKVSVK2TYS3FGR</RequestId>
<HostId>+Boe80nRJgbHZveVARRp40JiRcFu1aOIcKO5o3sHf1zuTc/HQ4qxTJO3LiDGdyYVFX7yIMy0kbk=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Did you add the permissions to make this bucket/object publicly accessible?

Comment: @JuanFontes Yes I did

Comment: Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. Please Edit your question to add details of how you have granted permission to make the object publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure that your bucket is publically accessible in the Permissions tab
2. Use the following as your bucket policy: (please use your bucket name in the Resource field)

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": [
               "s3:GetObject"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-Name/*"
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Now see if it works. Please let us know.
If you are still having errors, this link must be helpful: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-static-website-endpoint-error/